# What is meant by the Laminar boundary layer equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics, boundary-terms

I have a question and it is to briefly explain (do not derive) the laminar boundary layer equations. I need to understand what the underlying ideas and how the equations are employed. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you know already? What don't you know?

Comment: I only really know what they are and what a boundary layer is.

Comment: And have you typed "boundary layer" into your favorite search engine and looked at the page [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_layer), which has exactly that and more? Is there something there you don't understand? We expect you to put a little effort into the question before you ask it.